# join two tables into one big table

Tags: sql, database

I have two tables with the same columns, and I need to copy one table's rows to the other table's rows to create one big table with all the values from both tables.  Right now I am doing this query to return the same thing:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 from Table1
union
SELECT col1, col2, col3 from Table2
```

However, it seems horribly inefficient, and on my system is very slow (returns 1210189 records).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

May it work to just do:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 
INTO Table1
FROM Table2
```

Answer (score 11):

Start with union all:

```
select col1, col2, col3 from Table1
union all
select col1, col2, col3 from Table2
```

Your query is trying to deduplicate things, which would slow it down considerably.

Comment: I'm pretty certain deduplicate is a made-up word :-)

Comment: We use the word 'dedupe' (short for deduplicate) at work all the time :)

Comment: Data depuplication is a standard phrase in data warehousing and storage/backup situations.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this to fill the second table:

```
Insert into table2 select * from table1;
```

Or if you want to be more specific:

```
Insert into table2(col1, col2, col3) select col1, col2, col3 from table1;
```

(Note: some DBMSs might require putting parenthesis around the SELECT clause.)

Comment: Is it possible to do this where table1 has columns that table2 doesn't, so any values in those columns that table2 doesn't have are filled with NULLs?

Comment: @HashimAziz Yes, this is the default behaviour if you specify the column names.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best option is to create a view in sql server, this will optimize the performance of the query:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 from Table1
union all
SELECT col1, col2, col3 from Table2
```

(As other users said: "union" is used to select distinct values from two tables 
where as "union all" is used to select all values including 
duplicates from the tables.)

At the same time I  would restrict the number of rows I get from the database if i am writing them for a web and if this is giving me problems, with the new functions of Sql Server 2005 [row_number()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx), with this I would page results.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * into new table(your new table name) 
from table1.col1,table1.col2,table2.col1;
```

here columns can be your required columns .

Answer (score 0):

```
select * into newtable from table1
union all
select * from table2
```

Worked well. Guidelines, both tables have exact same column names :)