# Merge two tables into one with optional foreign key

Tags: sql, sqlite

Just as an example, we have two tables:

```
Foo {
   Id;
   value1;
   value2;
   barId;
}

Bar {
   Id;
   value3;
}
```

In the previous version of the app, `value3` is optional; therefore, we put it in a separate table. Now that we decided to make it a mandatory field and have modified the database schema as the following:

```
Foo {
   Id;
   value1;
   value2;
   value3;
}
```

During the migration, this is what we want to achieve:

If the original `barId` is `NULL`, we will assign `value3` with some default value, e.g. `0`. If the `barId` is not `NULL`, we will copy `value3` from the original `Bar` table. How do we achieve this?

I also notice a very similar question: [join two tables into one big table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327366/join-two-tables-into-one-big-table).
However, we cannot use `union all` because:

> Each SELECT statement within the UNION must have the same number of columns. [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. UNION is not what you want. UNION is for stacking result sets. In your case you wish to JOIN two tables:

```
SELECT foo.id, foo.value1, foo.value2, coalesce(bar.value3, 0) as value3
FROM foo 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN bar ON foo.barid = bar.id;
```

Here use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` so that we get ALL of our records from `foo` and only those records from `bar` that match on `id`. Then we use the `coalesce()` function which says "If `bar.value3` is null then use `0` as the value".